# jQueryUI Dialog Does Not Close

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I *think* I'm doing this right, but neither button actually closes. Either I'm blind or missing a subtlety.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scafrithuric/Bk2A9/3/)

HTML

```
<div id="sample-dialog" title="New Effect"></div>
<button>Button</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {

        $(function () {
            $("button")
                .button()
                .click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#sample-dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });

        $("#sample-dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close by $(#id)": function () {
                    $("#sample-dialog").dialog("close");
                },
                    "Close by $(this)": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    });

});
```

I started the process trying to follow and modify [this sample](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).

Comment: @JasonP: Thank you. Didn't get the "shareable" link right the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently wrapping the button click handler in `$(function() {...})` causes that to be executed after the function to create the dialog. The buttons in the dialog are, well, `<button>`s, so clicking them closes the dialog, but the click handler immediately reopens the dialog. It works without the extra `$(function() {...})`, which shouldn't be necessary anyway:

http://jsfiddle.net/nLvwp/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button")
        .button()
        .click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#sample-dialog").dialog("open");
    });

    $("#sample-dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close by $(#id)": function () {
                $("#sample-dialog").dialog("close");
            },
                "Close by $(this)": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

You could also solve the problem by being more specific in selecting the button that should open the dialog. But a single `$(document).ready(function{...})` or `$(function() {...})` (which do the same thing) is sufficient.

Comment: There was another answer for bit that demonstrated the fix by adding adding an id to the "original" button, but it's been deleted. My lesson is to be more careful with the function wrappers as I play around. Thank you.